# Load kernel image and file system via a boot loader

Tags: boot, tftp

I wish to use a boot loader (U-Boot for instance), and an ftp connection (via Ethernet) to load the kernel and the file system, and flash them.

I have done this procedure in the past on other boards, using minicom via a serial connection, u-boot boot loader, and a tftp server, but those only required some sort of interrupt during start up (on-board button, keyboard press sent via uart, etc...) in order to access their boot command line.

So I wonder if it is possible to do something similar on the pi, and if so, how?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to replace the pi's (proprietary?) bootloader with U-boot or anything else, but it [does look like](http://elinux.org/RPi_U-Boot) you can get it to load U-boot instead of a kernel, and go from there.

Comment: There is no flashable memory in the Pi.  All you can do is update the SD card memory with a kernel and filesystem.  Not sure if that would work either as you won't have access to the SD card during boot.

Comment: Did you succeed Edwin ? I'd like to do the same.